# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when trying to read huge PDF file to byte array

Tags: java, pdf, out-of-memory, arrays, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read huge pdf file using byte Array,
Here is my code for it.

```
String RESULT "D/new/certficateVisualFinal.pdf";
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;

        File file = new File(RESULT);

        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];


            //convert file into array of bytes
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();

        reader = new PdfReader(bFile);
        pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outPut));

        pdfStamper.setOutlines(outlineVisual);
        pdfStamper.setFormFlattening(true);

 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

But I got a OutOfMemoryErro when trying to

```
fileInputStream.read(bFile);
```

This is the Error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
```

please help me.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the byte array at all.  `PdfReader` has a constructor with an `InputStream` parameter, so you can just pass your `FileInputStream` directly to that.

Comment: i tried it before. here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235753/map-failed-java-io-ioexception-when-using-pdfstamper?noredirect=1#comment36272696_23235753

Comment: thats why im trying to another way.

Comment: OK, I read your other question just now.  Let's see if I understand this correctly.  You allocated 1GB, and ran out of memory reading this file; so you decided to try reading the entire 1.5GB of the file into the 1GB of memory to see if that would remove the out of memory error?